# Find determinant of the matrix $P$.

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, determinant

> Consider $J$ to be an $n\times n$ matrix whose entries are all $1s$ .
>
> If $P$ is an $n\times n$ matrix such that
>
> $P=$ \begin{bmatrix} v_1| v_2|,\ldots |v_{n-1} |v_n\end{bmatrix}
>
> where the columns $v_i=e_i-e_n$  for $1\le i\le n-1$ and $v_n=\sum e_i$ where $e_i$ is the ith column of the Identity Matrix

Note that $v_i,1\le i\le i-1$ are the eigen vectors corresponding to $0$ of $J$ and $v_n$ is an eigen vector corresponding to $n$ of $J$

> Find $\det P$.

It is very difficult to expand by Laplace Expansion

Is there any efficient way to to find the determinant?

Comment: How about doing it by induction and expanding with respect to the first line?

Comment: What does the matrix $J$ have to do with anything?

Comment: @BigbearZzz;Sorry forgot  to write that

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Hint**:

Add each row above to the last row, then expand by the last row.

Answer (score 1):

Use row operations to simplify the matrix in an upper triangular form. The form of $P$ is,
$$P=\begin{pmatrix}
1 &0&0& ...&1 \\
0&1&0&...&1\\
\vdots\\
-1&-1&-1&...&1
\end{pmatrix},$$
So carry out the row operation (which doesn't change the determinant) $R_n=R_n+R_k$ for $1 \leq k \leq n-1$. The resulting matrix is of the form
$$P'=\begin{pmatrix}
1 &0&0& ...&1 \\
0&1&0&...&1\\
\vdots\\
0&0&0&...&1+(n-1)
\end{pmatrix},$$
so $\det P=\det P'=1 \cdot 1 \cdot...\cdot1 \cdot n=n$.

Comment: It will be $n$ in the last entry of the matrix ,not $n+1$

Comment: That's what I wrote